# Can I change the icon of a mounted disk in Transmit?

Tags: icon, ftp

I noticed these icons in the resources folder of Transmit:
[image: icons]

I was wondering how I can change the standard cardboard mounted disk icon with the transmit logo to one of these. Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 3):

I did the following and it worked.

1. Open the .icns file by double-clicking it.
2. Press Cmd-C to copy the image.
3. Mount the FTP volume.
4. Click the mounted volume's icon on the desktop or in a window viewing the computer (Shift-Cmd-C in the Finder).
5. Click the icon in the top left.
6. Cmd-V to paste the icon in.

This creates an file at the root level of the volume called `.VolumeIcon.icns`, which when Mac OS X sees, uses it as the volume's icon. I successfully ejected the drive and remounted it and the icon was still there.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, all you have to do is change the disk's icon in Transmit. It will automatically assign the icon to the drive for you. When you are editing the favorite, just click the picture and choose a new one from the dropdown.